# Any AJAX experts, PLEASE help! AJAX-IM 1.0

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, instant-messaging

this website has been brilliant at helping me with probs in the past and i'm hoping it can help me again...basically I have just setup ajax im (http://ajaxim.com/ (version 1.0 form the old website because i want the most basic version possible)) using both WAMP (on my home computer), and on the works server. 
I have installed the database tables and changed the variables in the files to access the database. When i start it up (index.html) it shows the login form and when you register, it says "unable to regsiter try again later" and does not update the database.
I am guessing I am doing something wrong or there is some kind of file i need to run prior to this. 
If anyone can help it would be appreciated immensely.
Many thanks for any help :)

Please note: I have also asked this on the ajax-im forum but people on this site are extremely helpful and i'm hoping someone has had the same problem and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK ive just managed to get the latest version working. I've read up and the first is apparently not very good and almost impossible to get working anyway.